# If condition with auto filter

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, autofilter

I am trying to find blank cells in column "Issuer", and if there are blank cells, it should show rows with blank cells and a message box indicating there are blank cells however if there no blank cells, nothing should happen(no pop up message).

I have below code which is doing what's intended to do, however the pop-up message always appears even if there is no blanks.

```
Sub Filter()

If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
Dim ws As Object

    ActiveSheet.Range("H:H").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>Cash", _
        Operator:=xlAnd

SearchCol = "Issuer"

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Set rng1 = ws.UsedRange.Find(SearchCol, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    With ws.Range("A2")
        If .AutoFilter(Field:=rng1.Column, Criteria1:="") Then
        
        MsgBox ("Blank Coupan Rate")
        
        Else
        
        On Error Resume Next
End If

End With

Next ws

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you missing and `End If` in your code?

Comment: Hi, the code didn't copy properly, the remaining code is outside the grey area

Comment: You can edit your question and add the missing lines of code.

Comment: essentially it shouldn't do anything if no blanks are found in the column "Issuer". Just show all initial data